# In Javascript: memory allocation versus large object manipulation

Tags: javascript, memory

I have a JavaScript module that maintains and manipulates a lot of data. I have four large structures -- each basically an object of objects of objects of arrays. And there's a lot of data in them. When a user does something like delete or update something, I need to go through each of these structures and reliably modify the structure to reflect the change. In some structures, depending on the user action, I don't know *which* "leaf" object i need to change, so i have to iterate through all, etc.

An alternative to manipulating these large structures when a change takes place is to null them out and rebuild them from their raw data. And that's my question:

From a performance point of view, in Javascript, would it be more optimal to loop through and modify existing (large) data structures or simply rebuild the structures from their raw data?

I'm sure the answer might be "it depends" but a) assume large amount of data; b) assume frequent changes to that data.

Comment: Great question. I would guess that manipulating every node in a large structure would be less performant than rebuilding, as you're doing a get and set instead of just a set, but if you're only changing one thing in a huge structure then rebuilding would be less performant. But I'm just speculating - I have no evidence! :)

Comment: It's all a bit hypothetical but my approach would probably be to take the hit up front and break those big objects down into collections of smaller objects and arrays. Thus hopefully mitigating the uncertainty and the need for deep inspection.

Comment: Sounds like poorly planed data structure. People might be able to help you to structure better if you describe in more details what goal you have in mind.

Comment: Even looping, which is O(n), is *very fast* for a reasonable n/C combination; Big-O is only a bounds .. is there a performance problem? *If not, don't worry about the performance.* Although as suggested, it may be possible to clean up the model ..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know you're not expecting this answer, but "it depends" :-) However, I think the best answer I can give you is what I did when I faced exactly the same problem: I implemented myself a simple testbench to measure the time taken for doing certain operations on the huge superobject: I got mean time measures for different levels of information entropy and it turned that the fastest solution was rebuilding the structure from raw. I specially noticed this in Internet Explorer. Perhaps IE does not perform well in loops (I'm speculating) and traversing the superobject was quite slower than rebuilding it. So, it may not only depend on the structure of the superobject but also on the javascript engine.

But, again, it is my case. I recommend to implement yourself a simple testbench: it doesn't take too much time but makes you get good results at the end ;-)

**EDIT**:

Just as an addendum, I wonder whether building the superobject on the server's side and then sending it back to the browser as a JSON object would improve results or not. I don't know if it could be possible in your case. You could implement some sort of AJAX-accessible PHP script that receives commands (such as insert, delete, rename, whatever..) and then it'd send back the new JSON object to the browser, which would only parse the object (probably a fast operation??)

Comment: IE is hardly known for JS performance .. it's dead-last, sometimes by several factors, in most [micro] benchmarks I've seen. However, I think the important bit of this answer is **implement .. [a] testbench to measure** (so +1) .. as it will vary by what is being done, what resources are stressed, and on what implementation ..

Comment: Thank you @pst. Indeed, it is very frustrating to see a nice piece of code running OK in all browsers but in IE. And I say frustrating 'cause, you know, customers often stick in using IE and cannot understand it s**ks. I eventually lie them by saying that they should install Chrome/FF because they are required "platforms" to let the application run ¬¬ Funny but, again, frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's applicable here, but it reminds me of a [blog post from wingolog.org](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/07/05/v8-a-tale-of-two-compilers) about v8's implementation:

> Ed.: Vyacheslav Egorov writes in to say that what V8 keeps around is
>   actually the function source, not the AST. It re-parses as needed.
>   Makes sense. I recall Lars Bak saying in a video that source is the
>   most compact IR there is, and indeed maybe that is the case.

So basically, when v8 compiles JavaScript, it only keeps the raw data (source code) because in this case, the memory footprint is what affects performance most.